# Compilation error in jsp file "cannot find symbol: variable a location: class simplyfiedJSPServlet"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am try to learn session implicit object. Please check. In `index.jsp` I create one form. On clicking submit button it will redirect to `welcome.jsp`. In `welcome.jsp` I am creating session attribute and in same page we redirect to `second.jsp`. In second.jsp we will get the name through session. But in **welcom.jsp file is giving error. cannot find symbol: variable a location: class simplyfiedJSPServlet**.

[image]

index.jsp

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
               <h1> This for getting session implicit object </h1>
                <form action="welcome3.jsp">
                    <input type="text" name="uname">
                    <input type="submit" value="go"><br/>                    
                </form>                
        </body>
    </html>
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <% 
             String name=request.getParameter("uname");
             out.print("Welcome"+name);
             session.setAttribute("user", name);
             <a href ="second.jsp" > second jsp  </a>
         %>
    </body>
</html>
```

second.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
            String name=(String )session.getAttribute("user");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <error-page>
        <error-code> 500</error-code>
        <location> /error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `web.xml` and `simplyfiedJSPServlet.java` files?

Comment: @RRR please check it. I added. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have html tag inside java code ,

```
     <% 
         String name=request.getParameter("uname");
         out.print("Welcome"+name);
         session.setAttribute("user", name);
          <a href ="second.jsp" > second jsp  </a> // html anchor tag
     %>
```

should be outside of it,

```
<a href ="second.jsp" > second jsp  </a>
```

[what are scriptlets in jsp?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptlet)